# how to slove The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: .net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm3XC.png)
I got an exception on line no: 63

how to solve this error the ssl connection could not be established in dotnet core

Comment: Post any code and errors as text in the question itself. The *full exception text* includes any inner exceptions that may tell you why the connection couldn't be established. Quite often, it's because the remote services requires TLS1.2 but the application runs on an unsupported and upatched Windows version that doesn't support TLS1.2 by default. All *supported* .NET Core versions, ie 3.1, 6 and 7 will use the best algorithm provided by the OS. The oldest supported Windows version is Windows 10, which does support TLS 1.2. Older versions require patching

Comment: If the service requires TLS1.3, you'll have to use Windows 11. That's the first version that introduced TLS 1.3

Comment: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. and innerexception was "Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'."

Comment: That's not the full exception text. You already wrote the message in the question itself. The full text includes the location, call stack and any inner exceptions. You can get it easily with just `Exception.ToString()`. In Visual Studio or Rider there's a `Copy Details` in the exception popup. In web applications the exception screen displays the full exception details

Comment: In any case, what .NET Core and Windows version are you using? If you run on an outdated Windows TLS 1.2 won't be available. There are a *lot* of identical questions - the answer is to install the patch for the Windows version you use

Comment: [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) shows how to enable TLS 1.2 by default on Windows versions before 8.1 and Windows Server before 2012R2